# php goes to blank page, no errors, but does not input infi in database

Tags: php, forum

Thanks for your help, let me know if you need anything else.
details in the title.

```
<?php

$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$submit = $_POST['submit'];

if ($submit)

{
$connect = mysql_connect("host","un","psw");
mysql_select_db("rebeler_comment");

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table VALUES('','$subject','$comment')");
}


?>

<form action="form.php" method="POST">
<label>Subject</label></br>
<input type="text" name="subject"</br>
<label>Comment</label></br>
<textarea name="comment"></textarea></br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

updated with my html

Comment: echo your query and see what it says.

Comment: Have you installed the mysql database driver for PHP?

Comment: Use `mysql_error()` to catch errors. THis is shown in the manual http://php.net/mysql_query

Comment: Well, you're not outputting anything at all, whether you're successful or not. You're not checking to see if your query has worked. Does your form use POST? Is there an input called `submit`?

Comment: Also, use php instruction `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);` for safely say "no error".

Comment: try putting this before your code:<br>
    `ini_set('display_errors',1);error_reporting(E_ALL);`
That should make errors appear, once you know whats wrong come back for help. Also, you should echo $query.

Comment: **WARNING:** you are using a deprecated version of MySQL, which is susceptible to attacks and SQL injection. Please upgrade to make use of MySQLi. http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-to-use-php-improved-mysqli-extension-and-why-you-should

Comment: I updated it with my html as well, and I did have die(' thanks'); and it didn't say anything just a blank page

Comment: @david...did what you said and got "Undefined index: submit in /home3/rebeler/public_html/new/form.php on line 7"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the use of `MySQL_` is deprecated. Use `MySQLi_` and/or PDO.

Now, you're not specifiying `"where"` to put your data in your table.

Assuming your columns are named `subject` and `comment` respectively.

Also, the word `table` is a [**reserved**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) **word**. Therefore if your table is indeed called `table`, you need to wrap in inside back ticks,

```
like this: `table`
```

---

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (`subject`, `comment`) 
VALUES ('$subject','$comment')");
```

If table name is called "table":

Use:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`subject`, `comment`) 
VALUES ('$subject','$comment')");
```

Deleted `'',` from `('','$subject','$comment')` because you only have 2 values going in DB.

You may even want to concatenate such as:

```
VALUES ('" . $subject . "','" . $comment . "')");
```

To echo a success message:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`subject`, `comment`) 
VALUES ('$subject','$comment')");

echo "Data successfully written to DB";
}

else{
echo "Sorry, there was a problem.";
}
```

---

## EDIT 2:

```
<?php
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$connect = mysql_connect("host","un","psw");
mysql_select_db("rebeler_comment");

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`subject`, `comment`) VALUES ('" . $subject . "','" . $comment . "')");
$retval = mysql_query( $query, $connection ); if(! $retval ) { die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error()); }
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($connection);
}
?>
```

---

### EDIT 1:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`subject`, `comment`) VALUES ('" . $subject . "','" . $comment . "')");
$retval = mysql_query( $query, $connection ); if(! $retval ) { die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error()); }
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($connection);
```

Comment: followed ur directions on it and now I do get Sorry, there was a problem.";

Comment: @MosesBolton Do your DB fields match and is your table indeed called `table`?

Comment: @MosesBolton Plus try my **Edit** at the end. May be just a connection issue when trying to write to DB.

Comment: @MosesBolton If your table name is called "table" then it MUST be inside backticks. Look at my answer carefully. It's a [**MySQL Reserved Word.**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: //done and get this error now "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home3/rebeler/public_html/new/form.php on line 25"

Comment: @MosesBolton You're getting that error because you have a missing/closing `}` brace.

Comment: I copied and pasted your post, it is exactly like yours and to be more precise it is in backticks not double or single quotes

Comment: this is the new error.....Notice: Undefined index: submit in /home3/rebeler/public_html/new/form.php on line 7

Comment: oh and I did close the brackets to resolve the line 25 issues.....thank you again fred!!

Comment: @MosesBolton Your undefined index is because something is not matching in your DB column(s). And you're welcome. Is everything fixed and running?

Comment: @MosesBolton Does it work now? If yes, then please accept my answer to properly close the question as being answered so it does not remain in the unanswered category.

Comment: no it is not fixed sorry, got busy at work still giving me the undefined  line 7 issues

Comment: @MosesBolton What is line 7 exactly, the name etc.?

Comment: @MosesBolton See also **EDIT 2**

Comment: line 7 resolved, now for some reason its giving me an error saying access denied from my host

Comment: @MosesBolton That must surely be a username/password issue now.

Comment: yes I have had problems with the db before saying denied even though correct info, before this started happening it looked as though we got all necessary issues resolved, I just need to contact my host and see if this is on their side for the rst, ty again

Comment: @MosesBolton You're very much welcome. I hope it does get resolved, *cheers*

Answer (score 0):

Fix your SQL insert (among some things), define the columns to insert into, instead of blindly throwing stuff into the dark.

**Ex:**

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

Also use `mysql_error()` for get errors.  I would also suggest leveraging a php framework to get around injection issues and other stuff you might miss doing mysql by hand.